# TFS 2010 custom reporting SQL query to list all active branches per Release (branch name) & Project within a collection

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, merge, branch

Ever since I started to work with TFS 2010 (through VS 2008 if it matters) and was tasked with producing administrative reports, I have had a lot of challenges.  I know that there is an API and the Sidekick but neither give the details, scheduling capabilities, zero client involvement, or ease of use that my group requires.

After looking at one of the collection schemas, I only became more frustrated...  We aren't using the testing/lab piece of the tool, so the only database relationships available are of little use to us.

My department is heavily involved with reporting branch activity/maintenance/administration, where the primary focus of the canned TFS reports is more towards work items and burn rates (not useful to my department).

Ideally, I would like to know what SQL is involved to achieve this without having to run a profiler against a branching process, decipher the logs, and decrypt all involved SPs/functions/views to identify the programmatic connections between each table involved so that a SSRS report (2008r2) can be developed to provide this scheduled information more dynamically...

I can't be the only person in a Release Management department that wants this info... Can anyone help?

Comment: FWIW, one of the reasons my organization did not pursue TFS several years ago was precisely due to the lack of customizable, detailed reporting and auditing features. We saw a few, narrowly defined, canned reports, but realized we'd have to start rolling our own or do without.

Comment: unfortunately, this is what we have and the TFS ER model is yet to be desired.  The related tables portion of the model can fit on a 10x14 page print out, leaving ~100 programmatically referenced tables, some defined by complex calculations that define their alternate and foreign keys.  I've never seen anything like this before.  I haven't explored it yet but their SSAS Analysis cube appears to provide little, if any, assistance.

Comment: Hi Jason, are you just looking to find the branches that exist or does "active" mean something?  If you can give me a few more details, I can provide you with the tables to look at to determine this data.  Also, are you using branch objects?

Comment: @TaylorLafrinere, finding all branches that exist would be a start.  An active branch for us would be under a separate folder, branched from MAIN, both located under the project folder. The MAIN folder is always locked to the developer and after a release is deployed and verified, the release branch is locked and cloaked from the devs. An example of one of the reports that I'd like to create would detail all projects with active release branches (we also have YY-MM valued naming conventions built into our release folders)

Comment: A few more clarification questions/comments.  1. Can you run this SQL query against your collection? "select * from tbl_Branch".  Does that give you any results?  2. When you lock and cloak a branch, how do you do it specifically?  Do you take a checkout lock on the branch root?  Are all of these checkout locks taken in the same workspace?

Comment: @TaylorLafrinere Thanks but I was aware of the tbl_Branch table, which does contain all branches however, it isn't exclusive to active branches, it is more like branches processed (e.g. if we have an experimental branch that is renamed to a release branch, both will show in this table). As for Q2, first a batch job runs that removes permissions from each root release branch folder, branch code is merged to MAIN, then in VS, the branch folders are cloaked from the developers. I'm not sure what you mean by all checkout locks taken in the same workspace...